# BitmapFactory.decodeResource succeeds but mbuffer is null

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I am using BitmapFactory.decodeResource and everything is fine until I try it on a Kindle Fire.
BitmapFactory.decodeResource does not return null, and GetWidth etc are all correct but mbuffer (private) is null so the bitmap is blank.
I need to test at this point to see if its failed but I am not allowed to access mbuffer.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What are you doing?

Comment: I am loading in an image (a very large one) from resources and converting it to a bitmap. But it fails (mbuffer is NULL) on Kindle. Although mBuffer is null the actual bitmap is not null and has the correct dimensions etc.

Comment: So mbuffer is null. And you are not going to tell what mbuffer is or has to do with it?

Comment: mbuffer is a private variable of Bitmap.

Comment: And what does it have to do with your bitmap? Can you come to the point and show your code. Your post does not make sense without it.

Comment: with respect - I have made it very clear what I am asking and my post makes perfect sense. I am asking how to test if mbuffer in Bitmap is null?

Comment: Why do you think that mbuffer being null is a problem? You may have another problem like wrong resource for some category of devices.

Comment: I stop the program in the debugger and can see that it is null. it works on all devices except Kindle Fire. So - BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns an ID (not null). A call to bitmap.GetWidth() returns the correct width. But in the debugger I can see that mbuffer is null. Whan I repeat this on other devices mbuffer is non null and in the debugger I can access all its elements,

Comment: because I can see it is null in the debuuger - I hover the cursor over it and it says null.

Comment: But it’s internal implementation details of the Bitmap class. We don’t know for sure that it must always be non null. Maybe for some cases it’s ok to be null like something is lazy loaded or data is available somewhere else. You should base your tests on public stuff only.

Comment: but in this case it is null and the texture displays as all black.

Comment: And it is mbuffer which holds he pixel data so it cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decodeResource()` takes into account the device sceen properties. Apparently it can not decode in this way. Just try a different image. You cannot mess around with that buffer anyway. If you just want to get a bitmap then load images from raw or assets